# Return file from controller when model is not valid?

Tags: asp.net-core

How to return file from controller when model is not valid?

I am getting image file like this

```
var Image = Request.Form.Files.Where(f => f.Name == "Image").First();
```

How to return it into view when model state is not valid?

Comment: You can make client side validation.

Comment: I did, but thre is some hard logic that i don't want to use in client.

Answer (score 1):

You cant return file with your HTML(if not using base64 or bytes). But you can save client file on the server and return file name with file url to client and show him the file.